# How to hex edit an exe file safely?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a small puzzle/wargame which involves coding **Windows Forms in C#**..

To get to a certain level I need a password which is stored in an exe. The same exe allows me send that password to a default person which is stored in a **variable**. The password sending is accomplished by updating the given user's data in a MySQL database.

The challenge was that a user should hex edit the exe and change the default recipient to the user desired username. But when I **hex edited** the file and put the desired user name and tried to run it, it showed an error "**x.exe not a valid win32 application**"..

Is there a way to safely hex edit a file without encountering this error. Or is there a way to modify the source so that, just one variable may be safely edited using a hex editor..

Comment: Why not store the data somewhere else, e.g. in a config file?

Comment: You could always make your own "Trainer" and, while the application's loaded in memory, hijack that memory store and alter it (though this is a lot more volatile).

Comment: You are expecting your users to edit the binary as a feature?

Comment: @chibacity it sounds like it's some kind of hacking exercise/riddle. I don't think he's writing the program

Comment: Yes I could store it in a config file... Wonder how this thought never came to me.. The users are just learning the basic disassembling stuffs so had to come up with a simple idea.. But this is more complicated than I thought..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is not an illegal alteration of an executable...  (It sounds like a challenge in a contest, the way you have it worded.)

Most likely your change caused the program to no longer be able to verify the [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).  If you wish to successfully alter the exe, you need to recalculate the checksum.  (This is just one possibile explanation for why the exe was corrupted.)

Altering a compiled executable and having it work is tricky to say the least.  It's a pretty advanced topic and not likely something that can be answered fully here.

Comment: Yes tried this. But it still showed me the same error.. Thought it would work.. And yes it is a simple contest.

Answer (score 3):

Editing a PE image in hex is going to be difficult since you will need to update various parts of the PE image if you change the length of a section or if the EXE is signed you would also invalidate it.  The PE image spec can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119) if you want to understand all the fields you will need to update.  If you want a nice UI, I would use something like [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) to edit to PE image correctly.

You could also use `ildasm`, only for .NET assemblies, to disassemble the EXE, edit the IL, and then use `ilasm` to reassemble and run it.  This would eliminate the need to edit the PE image and be safer.

Comment: Wow.. I used to hex edit game files using some tutorial but never thought it will be this complicated.. Gonna go through this whole night.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing something similar before I remember I had to replace variables with same-length strings for it to work properly. e.g. "someone@example.com" could be replaced with "another@example.net" or "myname@anexample.us". If you're using Gmail this would be easier because "mynameis@gmail.com" [is the same as](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) "my.name.is...+slim.shady@gmail.com".

Though, I think @David Stratton's idea is probably more relevant to exe's. I'm pretty sure the files I edited were just data files (it was a long time ago), but I know everything worked then for me as long as I didn't add or remove any bytes in the middle of the file.

Answer (score 0):

When modifying strings inside EXE/DLL files it is important that the length of the string you are editing is kept the same, for example if I changed "Hello User" to "Welcome User", we overflowed the stack for 2 bytes.

This will obviously result in an error. In order to have a successful edit accomplished, it is important that the modified string you put does not overflow the string that you are inserting it on.

TLDR;

If the string you are editing is 12 characters long, you can only change 12 characters in total.